# Keras: Optimizing Tweet-Specific Pre-Trained Word Embeddings Layer

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, word-embedding

I'm working on a classification task where I would like to classify tweets into 5 different classes. I'm following the [Keras Github IMDB classification examples](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_lstm.py) for building models, but would like to modify the `Embedding` layer in this model. Instead of passing weights for initialization to the `Embedding` layer, I have word2vec weights that I would like to look up for each tweet in my dataset, so I can construct a matrix of (tweet_words x vector_dimension) for each tweet.

For example, the tweet "I'm so tired of hearing about this election #tuningout" would be represented as a matrix like:

```
     vector_dim1  vector_dim2  vector_dim3 ... vector_dimN
I'm  value1       value2       value3          valueN
so   value1       value2       value3          valueN
tired                 (... and so on...)
of
hearing
about
this
election
#tuningout
```

I'm doing this lookup because I have embeddings that are learned separately for different countries, and I would like to look up the specific embedding based on location of the tweet, instead of passing weights from a joint embedding to the `Embedding` layer for initialization. I can pass such a matrix directly to a really simple LSTM with the following Keras architecture:

```
model = Sequential()
# layer here would normally be:
# model.add(Embedding())
model.add(LSTM(width, input_shape=(max_len, 100), dropout_W=0.2, dropout_U=0.2))
model.add(Dense(class_size))
model.add(Activation(activation))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

but, the disadvantage of this compared to the example in the link is that this architecture cannot further optimize an `Embedding` layer. Is there a way to pass these matrices for each tweet to an Embedding layer for further optimization as in the example? Thanks for reading.